# Angular 2 Customize display of autocomplete with dynamic <ng-content>

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm creating an autocomplete component and I'm trying to figure out how I should handle the "display" of the item.  I've tried using `ng-content` and rendering the item but it fails. What I want is a  way to us `ng-content` and pass "data" to the child content.  When I try to pass content it always fails and says "item" is undefined.

```
<input-auto-complete
    [data]="searchResults"
    (onItemSelected)="onItemSelected($event)"
    (onSearch)="onSearch($event)">
       {{item.Name}}
</input-auto-complete>
```

In short I'm creating an input that does the autocomplete  / search but I can't figure out a good way to allow people to customize how they want to display the results.

I am using ionic but my template looks like:

```
<ion-searchbar
           [(ngModel)]="search"
            (ionInput)="updateSearch()"
            (ionCancel)="dismiss()">
</ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of data"
          tappable
          (click)="onItemSelected(item)">
         <!-- i found a way to do something like this where they can pass a function to display -->
         <ng-container *ngIf="!display">
            <pre>{{item|json}}</pre>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="display">
            {{display(item)}}
          </ng-container>


          <!-- could not get this to work this would be my preference allow people to put whatever in here and it would get rendered and passed "item" -->
         <!-- if i enable this it breaks  <ng-content ></ng-content>   ->
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

When this renders it crashes and says can't read Name of undefined. It's not passing anything to the ng-content.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?  Let me know if things dont make sense.

Comment: item may not have been initialized when it renders. Have you tried `item.?Name`

Comment: I'm not using any "async" data right now.  I have `searchResults` hard coded to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Unfortunately I don't have a solution to offer but I'm posting this here (vs in comments) for space and formatting.

Your code doesn't work because `item` is only defined in the context of the **child** (the autocomplete) and it's evaluated in the context of the **parent**. Therefore, when `item.Name` is evaluated in the parent, `item` is undefined.

I don't see an easy solution. Basically you want the ability to compile a string — what's inside the `<input-auto-complete>` element — as if it were a piece of another template — the template of `<input-auto-complete>`.

Here are a couple of ideas that I hope will help (none of them ideal, unfortunately):

**1. Expose the child's properties and methods to the parent template**

You can do that by declaring a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#ref-vars) on the child:

```html
<input-auto-complete #ac>
  <!-- Now you can access the data from the autocomplete via ac.data -->
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of ac.data">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</input-auto-complete>
```

NB. I haven't tested this. Be careful that `data` is async and might not be defined initially.

**2. Replace Angular's interpolation with your custom syntax**

Something like:

```html
<input-auto-complete>
  <div>__ITEM__</div>
</input-auto-complete>
```

Then in the child I would parse the above string to search & replace `__ITEM__` with its actual value. Very low-level, a bit of an anti-pattern (direct DOM manipulation is frowned upon) and it feels like reinventing the wheel...

**3. Replace `ng-content` with a `TemplateRef`**

It's my understanding that you wanna let your users provide a *blueprint* for how each item will be displayed in the autocomplete suggestions. I imagine you're going to want to repeat the provided markup dynamically.

I don't know that you can do that easily with `ng-content` (you can't do `<ng-content *ngFor="...">` for instance). It'd be easier with a `TemplateRef`.

To obtain the item "blueprint" markup as a TemplateRef, wrap it in a `<template>` tag:

```html
<input-auto-complete>
  <template #itemTemplate>
    <div>__ITEM__</div>
  </template>
</input-auto-complete>
```

You need to identify the template with:

- Either a template variable, i.e. `<template #itemTemplate>` ([ng-bootstrap modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) does that).
- Or a custom directive, i.e. `<template itemTemplateDir>` ([ng-bootstrap tabs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs) does that).

Then in the autocomplete component you can get a hold of the template with the `@ContentChild` decorator:

- Using the template variable name (quotes): `@ContentChild('itemTemplate') itemTpl`
- Or the directive class (no quotes): `@ContentChild(itemTemplateDir) itemTpl`

Finally you can print out templates according to your own rules with [ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(templateRef)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html#createEmbeddedView-anchor).